# How to split Data Frame into Rows of Fixed size and separate them with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have sequenced of data.frame in which one of the columns repeat itself every 21 rows. That is `V` column in `df`

`df` is like this;

```
set.seed(1)
No <- rep(seq(0,95,1),times=21)
AC <- rep(rep(c(78,110),each=1),times=length(No)/2)
AR <- rep(rep(c(256,320,384),each=2),times=length(No)/6)
AM <- rep(1,times=length(No))
DQ <- rep(rep(seq(0,15,1),each=6),times=3)
V <- rep(seq(100,2100,100),each=96)
R <- sort(replicate(3, sample(5000:6000,96)))

df <- data.frame (No,AC,AR,AM,DQ,V,R)
```

To organize the data I use `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df_1 <- df %>% group_by(AR,AC) %>% arrange(No)
```

To split the data according to `V` column change I use base function;

```
split <- split(df_1,rep(1:96,each=21))
```

The question is can I do this with `dplyr` or `tidyr`? And after splitting 
how can I separate odd and even numbered data?

Comment: What do you want to do after that with your splitted data? This may help to answer your question. If you want to `do` somethign with your `data.frame` "splitted" (aka. grouped) by `V` you could do `df %>% group_by(V) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: Can you specify `odd` data? There are severeal columns in your `data.frame`, according to which you want to split? Or do you mean by odd rows number 1,3,...?

Comment: @thothal after splitting the data becomes list. I want to have odd and even numbered of data inside of this list as different data.frames

Comment: @thothal `odd` data means odd numbers inside of the `list`. `split[3]` etc..

Comment: Someting like this `even <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, split[2 * (1:48)]))`? Becasue if this is the case you do not need to go through `split` and `arrange` at all...

Comment: @aoronbarlow are you interested in creating two data frames one with odd and the other with even numbers of splitting the existing data frame according to the `v` column values where rows with odd values of `v` are in one data frame and even in another?

Comment: @thothal yes. what about splitting with `dplyr` is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussions you can use `filter` straight away and there's no need to `arrange` first:

```
even <- df %>% filter(No %% 2 == 0)
odd  <- df %>% filter(No %% 2 == 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer its working. On the other hand I could't catch `%% 2==0 and %%2==1` ?

Comment: The `%%` is the modulo operator. Any even number can be divided by 2 w/o a rest, thus the modulo is equal to 0. Check out: `0:10 %% 2`. All even numbers (including `0`) will yield a `0`.